# Compute p-value of single value in arbitrary distribution (using java and apache.commons.math3)

Tags: probability, distributions, p-value, java

I want to compute the p-value of a single numeric value drawn from an arbirtary distribution.
The p-value should be comparable to p-values that have been computed with single distinict values drawn from sets (using the Chi-Square Test).
The distribution of the numeric data is propbably mostly normal distributed, but can sometimes be uniform or log distributed.

My application is a dataset that has numeric and distinct features. I want to rank the features for one particular instance according to the p-value of corresponding feature value compared with all values in the dataset of this feature.

I tried using the densitiy of EmpiricalDistribution, this is however no p-value:

```
    String all[] = { "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c" };
    String selected[] = { "c" };
    //-> converted to counts
    long countsAll[] = { 6, 4, 2 };
    long countsSelected[] = { 0, 0, 1 };
    System.out.println(TestUtils.chiSquareTestDataSetsComparison(countsAll, countsSelected));

    double allNumeric[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7 };
    double selectedNumeric = 5;
    EmpiricalDistribution dist = new EmpiricalDistribution(1);
    dist.load(allNumeric);
    System.out.println(dist.density(selectedNumeric));
```

The best I came up with was binning the numeric data and using the ChiSquare test as well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-value of a $\chi^2$ is done through a [lower incomplete gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_Gamma_function). $$CDF(\chi^2( df, x )) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{df}{2})}.\gamma( \frac{df}{2}, \frac{x}{2})$$ where $df$ is the degrees of freedom and $x$ the $\chi^2$-statistic.

If you are asking for the p-value of the empirical distribution it simply the ratio of the bins in the histogram to the left/right versus all the bins.

There are plenty of algorithms out there for p of the $\chi^2$. Here is one I have used (it is C/C++ but easily tranformed to Java). Ignore the df check I put in there - it is something I required for my data.

```
/*************************************************************************
Chi-square distribution

Returns the area under the left hand tail (from 0 to x)
of the Chi square probability density function with
v degrees of freedom.


                                  x
                                   -
                       1          | |  v/2-1  -t/2
 P( x | v )   =   -----------     |   t      e     dt
                   v/2  -       | |
                  2    | (v/2)   -
                                  0

where x is the Chi-square variable.

The incomplete gamma integral is used, according to the
formula

y = chdtr( v, x ) = igam( v/2.0, x/2.0 ).

The arguments must both be positive.

ACCURACY:

See incomplete gamma function


Cephes Math Library Release 2.8:  June, 2000
Copyright 1984, 1987, 2000 by Stephen L. Moshier
*************************************************************************/
double getChiSqPValue(int df, double testSt) const
{
    if(df < 2) 
    { return(-1.0); } 

    double result = incompleteGamma(df/2.0, testSt/2.0);
    return(result);
}


/*************************************************************************
Incomplete gamma integral

The function is defined by

                          x
                           -
                  1       | |  -t  a-1
 igam(a,x)  =   -----     |   e   t   dt.
                 -      | |
                | (a)    -
                          0


In this implementation both arguments must be positive.
The integral is evaluated by either a power series or
continued fraction expansion, depending on the relative
values of a and x.

ACCURACY:

                     Relative error:
arithmetic   domain     # trials      peak         rms
   IEEE      0,30       200000       3.6e-14     2.9e-15
   IEEE      0,100      300000       9.9e-14     1.5e-14

Cephes Math Library Release 2.8:  June, 2000
Copyright 1985, 1987, 2000 by Stephen L. Moshier
*************************************************************************/

double incompleteGamma(double a, double x) const
{
    double igammaepsilon;
    double ans;
    double ax;
    double c;
    double r;
    double tmp;
    double result;


    igammaepsilon = 0.000000000000001;
    if( x < 0 || a < 0 )
    {
        result = 0;
        return result;
    }
    if( x > 1 && x > a )
    {
        result = 1.0 - incompleteGammaC(a, x);
        return result;
    }
    ax = a*log(x)-x-lngamma(a);
    if( ax < -709.78271289338399 ) 
    {
        result = 0;
        return result;
    }
    ax = exp(ax);
    r = a;
    c = 1;
    ans = 1;
    do
    {
        r = r+1;
        c = c*x/r;
        ans = ans+c;
    }
    while(c/ans > igammaepsilon);
    result = ans*ax/a;
    return result;
}


/*************************************************************************
Complemented incomplete gamma integral

The function is defined by


 igamc(a,x)   =   1 - igam(a,x)

                           inf.
                             -
                    1       | |  -t  a-1
              =   -----     |   e   t   dt.
                   -      | |
                  | (a)    -
                            x


In this implementation both arguments must be positive.
The integral is evaluated by either a power series or
continued fraction expansion, depending on the relative
values of a and x.

ACCURACY:

Tested at random a, x.
               a         x                      Relative error:
arithmetic   domain   domain     # trials      peak         rms
   IEEE     0.5,100   0,100      200000       1.9e-14     1.7e-15
   IEEE     0.01,0.5  0,100      200000       1.4e-13     1.6e-15

Cephes Math Library Release 2.8:  June, 2000
Copyright 1985, 1987, 2000 by Stephen L. Moshier
*************************************************************************/
double incompleteGammaC(double a, double x) const
{
    double igammaepsilon;
    double igammabignumber;
    double igammabignumberinv;
    double ans;
    double ax;
    double c;
    double yc;
    double r;
    double t;
    double y;
    double z;
    double pk;
    double pkm1;
    double pkm2;
    double qk;
    double qkm1;
    double qkm2;
    double tmp;
    double result;


    igammaepsilon = 0.000000000000001;
    igammabignumber = 4503599627370496.0;
    igammabignumberinv = 2.22044604925031308085*0.0000000000000001;
    if( x <= 0 || a <=0 )
    {
        result = 1;
        return result;
    }
    if( x < 1 || x< a )
    {
        result = 1-incompleteGamma(a, x);
        return result;
    }
    ax = a*log(x)-x-lngamma(a);
    if( ax < -709.78271289338399 )
    {
        result = 0;
        return result;
    }
    ax = exp(ax);
    y = 1-a;
    z = x+y+1;
    c = 0;
    pkm2 = 1;
    qkm2 = x;
    pkm1 = x+1;
    qkm1 = z*x;
    ans = pkm1/qkm1;
    do
    {
        c = c+1;
        y = y+1;
        z = z+2;
        yc = y*c;
        pk = pkm1*z-pkm2*yc;
        qk = qkm1*z-qkm2*yc;
        if( qk != 0 )
        {
            r = pk/qk;
            t = abs((ans-r)/r);
            ans = r;
        }
        else
        {
            t = 1;
        }
        pkm2 = pkm1;
        pkm1 = pk;
        qkm2 = qkm1;
        qkm1 = qk;
        if( abs(pk) > igammabignumber ) 
        {
            pkm2 = pkm2*igammabignumberinv;
            pkm1 = pkm1*igammabignumberinv;
            qkm2 = qkm2*igammabignumberinv;
            qkm1 = qkm1*igammabignumberinv;
        }
    }
    while(t > igammaepsilon);
    result = ans*ax;
    return result;
}



/*************************************************************************
Natural logarithm of gamma function

Input parameters:
    X       -   argument

Result:
    logarithm of the absolute value of the Gamma(X).

Output parameters:
    SgnGam  -   sign(Gamma(X))

Domain:
    0 < X < 2.55e305
    -2.55e305 < X < 0, X is not an integer.

ACCURACY:
arithmetic      domain        # trials     peak         rms
   IEEE    0, 3                 28000     5.4e-16     1.1e-16
   IEEE    2.718, 2.556e305     40000     3.5e-16     8.3e-17
The error criterion was relative when the function magnitude
was greater than one but absolute when it was less than one.

The following test used the relative error criterion, though
at certain points the relative error could be much higher than
indicated.
   IEEE    -200, -4             10000     4.8e-16     1.3e-16

Cephes Math Library Release 2.8:  June, 2000
Copyright 1984, 1987, 1989, 1992, 2000 by Stephen L. Moshier
Translated to AlgoPascal by Bochkanov Sergey (2005, 2006, 2007).
*************************************************************************/
double lngamma(double x) const
{

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double p;
    double q;
    double u;
    double w;
    double z;
    int i;
    double logpi;
    double ls2pi;
    double tmp;
    double result;

    double sgngam = 1.0;
    logpi = 1.14472988584940017414;
    ls2pi = 0.91893853320467274178;
    if( x < -34 )
    {
        q = -x;
        w = lngamma(q);
        p = floor(q);
        i = floor(p+0.5);
        if( i%2==0 )
        {
            sgngam = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            sgngam = 1;
        }
        z = q-p;
        if( z > 0.5 )
        {
            p = p+1;
            z = p-q;
        }
        z = q*sin(PI*z);
        result = logpi-log(z)-w;
        return result;
    }
    if( x < 13 )
    {
        z = 1;
        p = 0;
        u = x;
        while( u >= 3)
        {
            p = p-1;
            u = x+p;
            z = z*u;
        }
        while( u <2 )
        {
            z = z/u;
            p = p+1;
            u = x+p;
        }
        if( z < 0 )
        {
            sgngam = -1;
            z = -z;
        }
        else
        {
            sgngam = 1;
        }
        if( u ==2 )
        {
            result = log(z);
            return result;
        }
        p = p-2;
        x = x+p;
        b = -1378.25152569120859100;
        b = -38801.6315134637840924+x*b;
        b = -331612.992738871184744+x*b;
        b = -1162370.97492762307383+x*b;
        b = -1721737.00820839662146+x*b;
        b = -853555.664245765465627+x*b;
        c = 1;
        c = -351.815701436523470549+x*c;
        c = -17064.2106651881159223+x*c;
        c = -220528.590553854454839+x*c;
        c = -1139334.44367982507207+x*c;
        c = -2532523.07177582951285+x*c;
        c = -2018891.41433532773231+x*c;
        p = x*b/c;
        result = log(z)+p;
        return result;
    }
    q = (x-0.5)*log(x)-x+ls2pi;
    if( x > 100000000 )
    {
        result = q;
        return result;
    }
    p = 1/(x*x);
    if( x > 1000.0 )
    {
        q = q+((7.9365079365079365079365*0.0001*p-2.7777777777777777777778*0.001)*p+0.0833333333333333333333)/x;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 8.11614167470508450300*0.0001;
        a = -5.95061904284301438324*0.0001+p*a;
        a = 7.93650340457716943945*0.0001+p*a;
        a = -2.77777777730099687205*0.001+p*a;
        a = 8.33333333333331927722*0.01+p*a;
        q = q+a/x;
    }
    result = q;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am already using the ChiSquare (χ2) Test for the distinct (nominal) features.
But it cannot be applied to numeric data, can it?

Comment: If you are asking for the p-value of the empirical pdf, it simply the ratio of the bins in the histogram (think about it) - I put it in the answer.

Comment: thats what I ended up doing as well (see last sentence of my question ;-)).
But is there no correct and less approximate solution?

Comment: Then you are doing it right :). If you knew the real distribution you would not be using the empirical one.

Comment: If you know the mix of distributions you got the data from model the weights with a mixed distribution and get the parameters from an MLE or an E-M algorithm.